# PagedCollectionView is not found even after using namespace

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, mvvm

I am trying to use pagedcollection View for my MVVM , but it is not popping up as I type which give message type or namespace could not found!

it ask me to create class! which I did then error goes, but this class will be created only for this page, it appears same error message for other pages if I created again,I searched to find it out, this is what I tried

1>  Namespace used by me was Using system.windows.data;

2> in client folder (program files) i couldn't locate this dll file!! i believe this might     be   the error,

so what should I do to fix it( I know I can download Dll) but why should it just not work, after using namespace

NOTE:

I am using framework 4.0, studio 2010 professional does this is anything to do ??

I even have framework 4.5, studio 2012 which list the pagedcollection, but not with 2010 ,4.0

Please give me answers if anyone knows, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

PagedCollectionView is only supported in Silverlight I believe - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.pagedcollectionview(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I thought I said in my post(MVVM), I am working on Silverlight project!!, this is where I am facing problem about PagedCollectionView

Comment: yeah, Ok guys I am working on Silverlight;) , any help that could solve this ??